# Select in Angular JS - I need the element and value attribute to be the same

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a json like this, stored in $scope.result:

```
{ "tips":["p1","p2","p3","p4"],"actualTip":"p4"}
```

And I need to do a comboBox with Angular. I did this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="one" ng-model="actualTip" ng-options="tips for tips in result.tips" ></select>
```

And its puts me a combobox like this:

```
<option value="0"> p1 </option>
<option value="1"> p2 </option>
<option value="2"> p3 </option>
```

I need that the text and value of the option have the same "value".

For ex:

```
<option value="p1"> p1 </option>
<option value="p2"> p2 </option>
```

Edit: I forgot to say that I need the combobox starts with the option selected that is in "actualTip"

How can I do this?

Comment: It sets the options to that, but the value set to the model will be what you want, it's internal in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet: http://codepen.io/rmadhuram/pen/leukx

Don't worry about the value Angular stores in the options. You will get the correct value you want in the scope variable (you can see that in the console).

Also, you just have to initialize the scope variable with the value you want.

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.result = { "tips":["p1","p2","p3","p4"],"actualTip":"p4"};

  $scope.onSelect = function() {
    console.log('selected: ' + $scope.actualTip);
  };

  $scope.actualTip = "p4"; 
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" id="one" ng-model="actualTip" ng-change="onSelect()" ng-options="tips for tips in result.tips" ></select>
  </div>
</div>
```